# Issue with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver1251" {
  name                         = "sqlserver1251"
  resource_group_name          = "template_grp"
  location                     = "North Europe"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "login"
  administrator_login_password = "password"
  minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"
}
```

I got error: A managed resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sqlserver1251" has not been declared
2023-01-14T12:48:30.2495026Z in the root module.

Can someone hel me with this?

```
### Creates Azure SQL server firewall rule
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "sql_server" {
  for_each = var.sql_server_firewall_rules

  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.template_grp.name
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.sqlserver1251.name
  start_ip_address    = each.value.start_ip_address
  end_ip_address      = each.value.end_ip_address
}
```

Comment: It should be `azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver1251.name` based on the code you added and not `azurerm_sql_server.sqlserver1251.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing @marko E 's comment as an answer.

```bash
I got error: A managed resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sqlserver1251" has not been declared 2023-01-14T12:48:30.2495026Z in the root module.
```

The Error already answers the question itself, there is no resource `azurerm_sql_server` in your code.

You have to change your resource `azurerm_sql_firewall_rule` with the following.

```
### Creates Azure SQL server firewall rule
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "sql_server" {
  for_each = var.sql_server_firewall_rules

  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.template_grp.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver1251.name ## modified ##
  start_ip_address    = each.value.start_ip_address
  end_ip_address      = each.value.end_ip_address
}
```

This will fix this error.